# How do I nest a CQL map collection inside a set collection?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to have a data that will output class and teachers as below:

```
CLASS A: John
CLASS B: Jane
CLASS C: Stan
```

This is my CQLSH:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects(
    name TEXT,
    class_and_teachers SET<FROZEN MAP<TEXT, TEXT>>,
    );
```

However, I got the error

```
no viable alternative at input 'MAP' (...   name TEXT,  class_and_teachers SET<[FROZEN] MAP...)
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try this example - put `map` into `<>` of the `frozen` keyword - `SET<FROZEN <MAP<TEXT, TEXT>>>` instead of `SET<FROZEN MAP<TEXT, TEXT>>`. This is required as `frozen` expects arguments:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects(
    name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    class_and_teachers SET<FROZEN <MAP<TEXT, TEXT>>>);

 insert into subjects (name,class_and_teachers) values ('A', {{ 'CLASS A': 'John' }});
 insert into subjects (name,class_and_teachers) values ('B', {{ 'CLASS B': 'Jane' }});
 insert into subjects (name,class_and_teachers) values ('C', {{ 'CLASS C': 'Stan' }});

select * from subjects;

 name | class_and_teachers
------+-----------------------
    C | {{'CLASS C': 'Stan'}}
    B | {{'CLASS B': 'Jane'}}
    A | {{'CLASS A': 'John'}}
```

Comment: As a follow up, how do I insert multiple  map into the set?  `insert into subjects (name,class_and_teachers) values ('Mathemathics', {{ 'CLASS A': 'John' },{ 'CLASS B': 'Jane' }});`

Comment: I'd guess it's to be `[{ 'CLASS A': 'John' },{ 'CLASS B': 'Jane' }]`  notice the square parentheses